# Performing actions on command line arguments in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C that takes 10 command line arguments and performs certain actions on them. I already have the part that accepts the 10 arguments `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and the part that outputs the result once all 10 are entered by the user `printf("  %s", argv[i]);`.

I'm just trying to figure out how to perform the actions themselves on each command line argument entered, namely:

- remove all special symbols such as `(*&%^’$+_`.
- remove all non-letters

and finally:

- If the argument contains one or more digits, assuming that the first
  digit seen is n,  replace that arg by the nth arg (the only exception is 0, which should map to the 10th argument). So for example, if the argument entered is `764`, this argument gets replaced by the 7th arg.

**Edit:** Updated with better example below

Here is an example input (10 user-inputed arguments):

```
sda 789 io90 poi 4kl24PP +df_1JK MN BV XC __5555
```

and what the output should be:

```
sda  MN  XC  poi  poi  sda  MN  BV  XC  klPP
```

(also notice how 789 maps to the 7th output, which is MN)

Comment: If all non-letters are removed, there will never be any digits in the input...

Comment: Command line arguments are strings. How would you normally remove special symbols from a string?

Comment: What is the actual question here? From the sound of it, this has nothing to do with argv, and just your desire to manipulate strings in C.

Comment: @H2CO3 it's supposed to replace any argument that starts with a digit with the nth argument, see updated example above.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart i'm trying to manipulate user inputs in a certain way (see 3 bullet points above) and print modified user inputs. I want to know how I can manipulate the input in such a way consistant with the 3 bullet points in the question.

Comment: @Tangler Search for the first digit in each argument. If it's found, replace that argument with a symbol- and number-less copy of the nth arg, else replace it with a symbol- and number-less copy of itself.

Comment: What happens if the mapped-to argument has numbers in it,too?

Comment: And is this a homework assignment, or is this for a real application? It seems nonsensical, which makes me assume the former. If it is homework, then this is disappointing because you've done nothing other than state your requirements.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart then it outputs nothing for that argument as all non-letters in the nth argument are removed

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it's a non-marked. I'm not sure how to do it and this is a Q&A site.

Comment: But it's a Q&A site that expects you to show effort, which you haven't demonstrated. Aside from some boilerplate code, you've only stated your requirements and asked us to do the work. You have to *try*something first. We'll help guide you through specific problems you're having.

Comment: Also, I don't know what a non-marked is. But regardless, we're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's my comment as an answer: search for the first digit in each argument. If it's found, replace that argument with a symbol- and number-less copy of the nth arg, else replace it with a symbol- and number-less copy of itself. C99 implementation:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *copies[argc - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        size_t p = strcspn(argv[i], "0123456789");
        int n = argv[i][p] ? argv[i][p] - '0' : i;
        if (n == 0) n = 10;
        char *copyee = argv[n];

        size_t l = strlen(copyee);
        copies[i - 1] = malloc(l + 1);
        char *copy = copies[i - 1];
        for (; *copyee; copyee++) {
            if (isalpha(*copyee)) {
                *copy++ = *copyee;
            }
        }
        *copy = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        printf("%s ", copies[i]);
        free(copies[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to check the return value of `malloc()` against `NULL`, that's omitted here for simplicity.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)` declaring `int i` in the for is not portable for all compiler it's valid in C > C99

Comment: You have to add `#include <ctype.h>` for the isalpha function

Comment: @MOHAMED That's why I stated in the answer that it's a C99 answer.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to select an answer. After testing it with a few more data sets, it does indeed do exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct inputcmd {
    char *cmd;
    int index;
}inputcmd;



int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    struct inputcmd icmd[10] = {0};
    char *newargv[10];
    int i;
    char *p, *s;
    if(argc!=11) {printf("You should input 10 commands\n"); return;}
    for (i=1; i<11; i++)
    {
        icmd[i-1].cmd = calloc(strlen(argv[i])+1, sizeof(char));
        p=argv[i]; s=icmd[i-1].cmd;
        while(*p) {
            if(isalpha(*p))
                *s++=*p;
            else if ((*p>='0' && *p<='9') && icmd[i-1].index==0) {
                if (*p=='0') icmd[i-1].index = 10;
                else icmd[i-1].index = *p - '0';
            }
            p++;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (icmd[i].index) newargv[i] = strdup(icmd[icmd[i].index - 1].cmd);
        else  newargv[i] = strdup(icmd[i].cmd);
    }
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        free(icmd[i].cmd);
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%s ",newargv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Execution 1**:

```
$ ./test sda 789 io90 poi 4kl24PP +df_1JK MN BV XC __5555
sda MN XC poi poi sda MN BV XC klPP
```

**Execution 2**:

```
$ ./test a2b c2d e2f g2h i2j k2l l2m n2n o2p q2r
cd cd cd cd cd cd cd cd cd cd
```

Comment: `if((*p>='a' && *p<='z') || (*p>='A' && *p<='Z') )` is not portable and `strlen(str)` is not enough place for a string...

Answer (score 0):

H2CO3's is a bit smaller than mine, but here's another quick implementation of your question.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char **original = argv + 1;
    char *messages[10] = {0};

    if (argc != 11) {
        printf("We expect 10 arguments.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Allocate space for the copied data.
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        messages[i] = calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(original[i]) + 1);

    // Let's parse out the parts of the mutable array that we don't want to keep.
    // So kill everything but letters
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        int head = 0;
        int tail = 0;

        while (original[i][tail] != '\0') {
            if (isalpha(original[i][tail])) {
                messages[i][head] = original[i][tail];
                head++; tail++;
            } else {
                tail++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Now, let's parse each message, and see what we are supposed to print.
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        char *pos = strpbrk(original[i], "0123456789");

        if (pos == NULL) {
            printf("%s ", messages[i]);

        } else {
            int index = *pos - '0';
            if (index == 0)
                index = 10;
            printf("%s ", messages[index - 1]);
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        free(messages[i]);

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: That switch-case should really be refactored, and your program is also leaking memory.

Comment: @H2CO3: I'll more or less agree.

Comment: I see all that is fixed now.